# Load average for specific time with all programms

Tags: performance, top, load-average

I'm searching for a linux tool to make some "performance tests". I have two (or more versions) of programms wihch do the same. To compare versions with each other I want to run these for a specific time (something between 30s and 5m) and then see their load average in the running system for the whole time (e.g. my programm foo needs in 2min about 30% of the system time). To do this in a comfortable way it would be nice to see the whole average system, because the various versions don't consists of one programm with one ID rather than a collection of programms. So if its possible to have a output into a log file then I can search manually for programms which are interesting.

Do anyone know such a program and can help me how to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Stat by process could be found in

```
/proc/$PID/stat
```

You could read documentation by running `man proc`, search for `/proc/[pid]/stat`:

```
man -P'less +/\\\/proc\\\/\\\[pid\\\]\\\/stat' proc
```

> ...
>
> (14) utime  %lu
>             Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode,  measured  in  clock
>             ticks  (divide  by  sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)).  This includes guest time, guest_time (time
>             spent running a virtual CPU, see below), so that applications that are  not  aware  of
>             the guest time field do not lose that time from their calculations.
>
> (15) stime  %lu
>             Amount  of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode, measured in clock
>             ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)).

**Nota:** The other fields could be important, for sample if your tool generate many subprocess (children).

For sample, there is a quick perl doing this job, but with a fixed delay of 1 second:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my ( $lut, $lst ) = ( 0, 0 );
my $pid = $ARGV[0] or die "No pid";

open FH, "</proc/$pid/stat" or die "Can't open \`\`/proc/$pid/stat''";
open UT, "</proc/uptime"    or die "Can't open \`\`/proc/uptime''";

sub getvals {
    seek FH, 0, 0;
    seek UT, 0, 0;
    my $st  = <FH>;
    my $ut  = <UT>;
    my $out = $lut;
    my $ost = $lst;
    $lut = ( split " ", $ut )[0] * 100;
    $lst = eval( join( "+", ( split " ", $st )[ 13, 14 ] ) );
    return $lut - $out, $lst - $ost;
}
getvals;
$| = 1;
while (1) {
    sleep 1;
    printf "%7.2f%%\n", eval sprintf "100/%s*%s", getvals;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and try to help me. I think this is not helpful for me, because there are, like I said, a huge number of processes to collect. So I must search for all pids for these processes and run the same number of instances of your script started at the same moment...
I thought there is any chance to say to `top` something like: I want a system statistic for the time of 60s with average from the individually processes...

Comment: you could modifiy this script or write your own,.. read values for many files in same field and sumarize is not a big job.